# cmake does not see Qt4

Tags: qt4, cmake, pyside

**NOTE**: not the same problem as question "make cannot find Qt4"!

Hi. There are a lot of very similar questions to this out there but I couldn't find one with so clear a problem. I need to install pyside on Scientific Linux 5.8. I've over come most dependency issues with some difficult and now I'm trying to build pyside from source.

I've git clone'd the required directories, now cd'ing first into apiextractor/ and running

```
]$ mkdir build
]$ cd build
]$ cmake ../
```

... fails with the cmake error:

```
 Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
```

However, I have installed qt47 and qt47-devel from the atrpms-testing repository. Looking in /usr/lib64/

```
]$ /usr/lib64/qt*
```

... produces:

[image: screen shot of my virtual machine]

So my question is fairly straightforward: why is cmake (specifically the command "find_package(Qt4 4.5.0 REQUIRED)") not finding Qt 4.7 when it is there and located where you would expect.

NOTE: I'm using cmake-2.8 as required.

Cheers,

Derek

Comment: It looks like you've got an older version installed too (Qt 3.3) - have you tried uninstalling that?  If you do, you should probably delete your CMakeCache.txt in the root of your build tree before re-running CMake, or even delete the whole build tree to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Fraser; Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. Fraser, yes I realize this, but cmake is designed for just this occasion. It is the CMake command is first finding Qt and then checking it's version, if the version is not correct it should keep looking other wise report the error 'unsuitable Qt version "3.3" from ...'. In this case it is simply not finding any instance of the Qt library.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that cmake relies on qmake to determine the layout of the Qt libraries. So if your system has several versions of Qt installed, you will have to take care to specify which qmake you want cmake to use, e.g:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=path/to/qt4/qmake
```